# recursive method ,always print out the same thing

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

 const int max = 8;
 bool checkvalid(int* array, int row1, int col)
{
      for(int j=0; j<row1; j++)
        {
           if( array[j] == col)  //not in the same colon
             return false;
            if( ((row1- j) == ( array[j]-col)) || ((row1- j) == ( -array[j]+col)) ) // not in the same diagonal
               return false;

         }
return true;
}

void placequeen(int row, int* array, std::vector<int*> &myvector)
{
     if( row == max)
     {       
          myvector.push_back(array);  // if I print here , result is correct
         /* for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
           std::cout << array[i] ;
           std::cout << std::endl;*/
     }
 else
     {

          for(int i=0 ; i<max; i++)
          {  

              if(checkvalid(array, row, i))
               { 
                 array[row] = i;
                 placequeen(row+1, array,myvector);
                }

              }

         }
   }


int main()
{
 std::vector<int*> a;
 int* array = new int[8];
 placequeen(0,  array, a);

for(std::vector<int*>::iterator it=a.begin(); it!=a.end(); it++)
  {    
        for(int i=0 ; i<8; i++)
        { 
         std::cout << (*it)[i] ; }
          std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

It's the n queen problem from cracking the code interview.It prints the same result "75364424" all the time . But if I print inside the if(row == max ) the result is correct (I toggle the code there), why and how to change? Thanks

Comment: Use `std::array<int, 8>` instead of raw owning pointer...

Comment: You store always the same **pointer** inside `myvector`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for explanation! I understand now!

Comment: Trick interview question. The right answer is, "Well known problem. Rather than waste the company's time reinventing the wheel, I'll look up solutions online, select one that meets the project requirements with the lowest amount of time and money spent upfront and in maintenance, and move on to the next problem."

Comment: @user4581301 I see. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From @Jarod42's  comment, I know I have to change pointer inside the vector to
std::array. In my former code, I store the same pointer inside the vector again and again.
    #include
    #include

```
 const int max = 8;
 bool checkvalid(std::array<int, 8> array, int row1, int col)  // change array* to  std::array<int, 8> array
{
      for(int j=0; j<row1; j++)
        {
           if( array[j] == col)  //not in the same colon
             return false;
          if( ((row1- j) == ( array[j]-col)) || ((row1- j) == ( -array[j]+col)) ) // not in the same diagonal
            return false;

         }
return true;
}

void placequeen(int row, std::array<int, 8> array, std::vector<std::array<int, 8>> &myvector)  // change array* to std::array<int, 8> array
{
     if( row == max)
     {    
           myvector.push_back(array);  // if I print here , result is correct

     }
    else
     {

          for(int i=0 ; i<max; i++)
          {  

              if(checkvalid(array, row, i))
               { 
                 array[row] = i;
                 placequeen(row+1, array,myvector);
                }

            }

         }
   }


int main()
{
   std::vector<std::array<int, 8>> a;
   std::array<int, 8> array;
   placequeen(0,  array, a);

  for(std::vector<std::array<int, 8>>::iterator it=a.begin(); it!=a.end(); it++)
  {    
       for(int i=0 ; i<8; i++)
       { 
         std::cout << (*it)[i] ; }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: For the answer to be useful to future readers, you should show the corrected version of the code.